# NAudio MMDevice.Properties.SetValue E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: naudio

Using MMDevice.Properties.SetValue to update a property and getting E_ACCESSDENIED.

Analogous code in C++ succeeds.

I notice that some of the VT_TYPEs of PROPVARIANT are not implemented in NAudio (e.g., VT_BSTR). Given that some of this is incomplete compared to C++, is SetValue() also incomplete (i.e., the API exists but is not implemented)?

```
            string state = ...;

            MMDevice endpoint = DeviceEnumerator.GetDevice("{0.0.0.00000000}.{FA456CEC-4A7C-4C51-8DD9-81525B559692}");
            PropertyKey PKEY_My_PropertyKey = new PropertyKey(Guid.Parse("{XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-xxxxxxxxxxxx}"), 6);

            NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces.Blob blob = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces.Blob();
            // Marshal the string variable into the BLOB structure.
            blob.Length = state.Length * 2 + 2;
            blob.Data = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(state);
            try
            {
                NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces.PropVariant statePV = new NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces.PropVariant
                {
                    vt = (short)VarEnum.VT_BLOB,
                    blobVal = blob
                };

                endpoint.Properties.
                endpoint.Properties.SetValue(PKEY_My_PropertyKey, statePV);
                endpoint.Properties.Commit();
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(blob.Data);
            }
```

The `endpoint.Properties.SetValue(PKEY_My_PropertyKey, statePV)`  call throws an System.UnauthorizedAccessException from an HRESULT of E_ACCESSDENIED.

I expected it to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the following is needed

```
endpoint.GetPropertyInformation(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.Interfaces.StorageAccessMode.ReadWrite);
```